# iterating through JSON hash on serialized model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, json, ruby-on-rails-3.1

how iterating through serialized hash and show just keys on the view?

**policy model**

```
class Policy < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
   serialize :shipping, JSON
end
```

**index**

```
<% @policy.shipping.each do |key, value|%>
<ul><li><%= key %></li></ul>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hash has a `keys` method, which returns its keys. So you can do the same with the following code:

```
<ul>
<% @policy.shipping.keys.each do |key| %>
  <li><%= key %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

You should also note that the `<ul>` tag should not be inside the loop.